# Stop an array while finding string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```js
function f() {
  var string1 = "Cyan | Magenta | Yellow | Cut | Information | Pink | Lila | White";

  var string2 = "Color | Color | Color | Technical | Technical | Color | Color | Color";

  var firstlength = string1.split("|").length;
  var secondlength = string2.split("|").length;
  var maxilength = firstlength;
  if (secondlength > firstlength)
    maxilength = secondlength;

  var string1split = string1.split("|");
  var string2split = string2.split("|");

  var concatstr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < maxilength; i++) {
    if (string1split.length > i) {
      concatstr += string1split[i];
    }
    if (string2split.length > i) {
      concatstr += string2split[i];
    }
    if (i < maxilength - 1) {
      concatstr += "|";
    }
  }


  {

    var colors = concatstr;

    var colorsarray = colors.split("|")
    var realcolorsarray = []

    for (i = 0; i < colorsarray.length; i++) {
      if (realcolorsarray.indexOf(colorsarray[i]) == -1) {
        realcolorsarray.push(colorsarray[i])

      }

    }

    var colorline = realcolorsarray.join("|")

    return colorline;

  }

}

f();
```

**This is my result:**

*Cyan Color | Magenta Color | Yellow Color | Cut Technical | Information Technical | Pink Color | Lila Color | White Color*

But i don't want the Color-Information behind the Technical Colors:

*Cyan Color | Magenta Color | Yellow Color*

Comment: _I only need the information before the Technical_  then why include `Cut Technical` in the result? Also, share your current approach.

Comment: Hi Heike, what is your question? How did you try it so far? Can you please share some code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*"But i don't want the Color-Information behind the Technical Colors"*

What I got from this line and the example result you gave after is you want only the colors before the ones including `Technical` so here it is:

You need a break in first `for` if the current item from string2 is `"Technical"`

```js
function f() {
  var string1 = "Cyan | Magenta | Yellow | Cut | Information | Pink | Lila | White";

  var string2 = "Color | Color | Color | Technical | Technical | Color | Color | Color";

  var firstlength = string1.split("|").length;
  var secondlength = string2.split("|").length;
  var maxilength = firstlength;
  if (secondlength > firstlength)
    maxilength = secondlength;

  var string1split = string1.split("|");
  var string2split = string2.split("|");

  var concatstr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < maxilength; i++) {
    if (string2split[i].trim() == "Technical") {
      break;
    }
    if (string1split.length > i) {
      concatstr += string1split[i];
    }
    if (string2split.length > i) {
      concatstr += string2split[i];
    }
    if (i < maxilength - 1) {
      concatstr += "|";
    }
  }


  {

    var colors = concatstr;

    var colorsarray = colors.split("|")
    var realcolorsarray = []

    for (i = 0; i < colorsarray.length; i++) {
      if (realcolorsarray.indexOf(colorsarray[i]) == -1 && colorsarray[i] != "") {
        realcolorsarray.push(colorsarray[i])

      }

    }

    var colorline = realcolorsarray.join("|")

    return colorline;

  }

}

console.log(f());
```